# Error in JDOQL query, FROM clause not recognized in Apache ISIS metamodel validation

Tags: datanucleus, isis

My SQL Query generates error in JDOQL query, class name for FROM clause not recognized in meta model validation.

I have defined the following queries :

```
@javax.jdo.annotations.Queries(Array(
  new javax.jdo.annotations.Query(
    name = "findByDescriptiveName",
    value = "SELECT "
      + "FROM domainapp.modules.system.dom.impl.FileObject "
      + "WHERE descriptiveName.indexOf(:descriptiveName) >= 0 "),
  new javax.jdo.annotations.Query(
    name = "findByApplicationComponent",
    language="SQL",
    value = "SELECT * "
      + "FROM FileObject ",
    resultClass=classOf[FileObject] )
  )
)
```

The findByApplicationComponent query language is defined as "SQL" but the isis metamodel validation reports the following :

```
domainapp.modules.system.dom.impl.FileObject: error in JDOQL query, class name for FROM clause not recognized (JDOQL : SELECT * FROM FileObject)
```

It seems that the metamodel validator is thinking that the language is JDOQL and not SQL. It is either that or I am doing something wrong. Can someone please advise.

I am using MySql as the database.

Comment: why not post complete exception + stack trace? and version of software being used

Comment: More than likely that is coming from Apache ISIS (in the absence of a stack trace), and you should report it to them, via their mailing list.